# Failed to inflate only on prod

Tags: android

Hello i have upload my new application to the google play store.

When i download my app from the play store and open it i got this error:

```
0-10 09:05:21.605: W/dalvikvm(22966): method Lorg/holoeverywhere/widget/aw;.getVirtualChildCount incorrectly overrides package-private method with same name in Landroid/widget/LinearLayout;
10-10 09:05:21.715: W/dalvikvm(22966): method Lorg/holoeverywhere/widget/ProgressBar;.getCurrentDrawable incorrectly overrides package-private method with same name in Landroid/widget/ProgressBar;
10-10 09:05:21.725: E/ActivityThread(22966): Failed to inflate
10-10 09:05:21.725: E/ActivityThread(22966): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class org.holoeverywhere.widget.ProgressBar
10-10 09:05:21.725: E/ActivityThread(22966):    at org.holoeverywhere.k.a(Unknown Source)
10-10 09:05:21.725: E/ActivityThread(22966):    at org.holoeverywhere.k.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
10-10 09:05:21.725: E/ActivityThread(22966):    at org.holoeverywhere.k.a(Unknown Source)
10-10 09:05:21.725: E/ActivityThread(22966):    at org.holoeverywhere.k.a(Unknown Source)
10-10 09:05:21.725: E/ActivityThread(22966):    at org.holoeverywhere.k.inflate(Unknown Source)
10-10 09:05:21.725: E/ActivityThread(22966):    at org.holoeverywhere.k.inflate(Unknown Source)
10-10 09:05:21.725: E/ActivityThread(22966):    at android.support.v4.app._HoloActivity.a(Unknown Source)
10-10 09:05:21.725: E/ActivityThread(22966):    at android.support.v4.app._HoloActivity.setContentView(Unknown Source)
10-10 09:05:21.725: E/ActivityThread(22966):    at com.example.workoutlog.OpeningPage.onCreate(Unknown Source)
10-10 09:05:21.725: E/ActivityThread(22966):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
10-10 09:05:21.725: E/ActivityThread(22966):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
10-10 09:05:21.725: E/ActivityThread(22966):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2262)
10-10 09:05:21.725: E/ActivityThread(22966):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
10-10 09:05:21.725: E/ActivityThread(22966):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
10-10 09:05:21.725: E/ActivityThread(22966):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
10-10 09:05:21.725: E/ActivityThread(22966):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-10 09:05:21.725: E/ActivityThread(22966):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-10 09:05:21.725: E/ActivityThread(22966):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
10-10 09:05:21.725: E/ActivityThread(22966):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-10 09:05:21.725: E/ActivityThread(22966):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-10 09:05:21.725: E/ActivityThread(22966):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
10-10 09:05:21.725: E/ActivityThread(22966):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
10-10 09:05:21.725: E/ActivityThread(22966):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-10 09:05:21.725: E/ActivityThread(22966): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
10-10 09:05:21.725: E/ActivityThread(22966):    at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
10-10 09:05:21.725: E/ActivityThread(22966):    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:431)
10-10 09:05:21.725: E/ActivityThread(22966):    ... 23 more
10-10 09:05:21.755: D/AndroidRuntime(22966): Shutting down VM
10-10 09:05:21.755: W/dalvikvm(22966): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41f86930)
10-10 09:05:21.755: E/AndroidRuntime(22966): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-10 09:05:21.755: E/AndroidRuntime(22966): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tigo/com.example.workoutlog.OpeningPage}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class org.holoeverywhere.widget.ProgressBar
10-10 09:05:21.755: E/AndroidRuntime(22966):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2308)
10-10 09:05:21.755: E/AndroidRuntime(22966):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
10-10 09:05:21.755: E/AndroidRuntime(22966):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
10-10 09:05:21.755: E/AndroidRuntime(22966):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
10-10 09:05:21.755: E/AndroidRuntime(22966):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-10 09:05:21.755: E/AndroidRuntime(22966):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-10 09:05:21.755: E/AndroidRuntime(22966):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
10-10 09:05:21.755: E/AndroidRuntime(22966):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-10 09:05:21.755: E/AndroidRuntime(22966):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-10 09:05:21.755: E/AndroidRuntime(22966):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
10-10 09:05:21.755: E/AndroidRuntime(22966):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
10-10 09:05:21.755: E/AndroidRuntime(22966):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-10 09:05:21.755: E/AndroidRuntime(22966): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class org.holoeverywhere.widget.ProgressBar
10-10 09:05:21.755: E/AndroidRuntime(22966):    at org.holoeverywhere.k.a(Unknown Source)
10-10 09:05:21.755: E/AndroidRuntime(22966):    at org.holoeverywhere.k.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
10-10 09:05:21.755: E/AndroidRuntime(22966):    at org.holoeverywhere.k.a(Unknown Source)
10-10 09:05:21.755: E/AndroidRuntime(22966):    at org.holoeverywhere.k.a(Unknown Source)
10-10 09:05:21.755: E/AndroidRuntime(22966):    at org.holoeverywhere.k.inflate(Unknown Source)
10-10 09:05:21.755: E/AndroidRuntime(22966):    at org.holoeverywhere.k.inflate(Unknown Source)
10-10 09:05:21.755: E/AndroidRuntime(22966):    at android.support.v4.app._HoloActivity.a(Unknown Source)
10-10 09:05:21.755: E/AndroidRuntime(22966):    at android.support.v4.app._HoloActivity.setContentView(Unknown Source)
10-10 09:05:21.755: E/AndroidRuntime(22966):    at com.example.workoutlog.OpeningPage.onCreate(Unknown Source)
10-10 09:05:21.755: E/AndroidRuntime(22966):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
10-10 09:05:21.755: E/AndroidRuntime(22966):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
10-10 09:05:21.755: E/AndroidRuntime(22966):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2262)
10-10 09:05:21.755: E/AndroidRuntime(22966):    ... 11 more
10-10 09:05:21.755: E/AndroidRuntime(22966): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
10-10 09:05:21.755: E/AndroidRuntime(22966):    at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
10-10 09:05:21.755: E/AndroidRuntime(22966):    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:431)
10-10 09:05:21.755: E/AndroidRuntime(22966):    ... 23 more
```

When i run the application from eclispe i dont get any of this error and everyting just running fine.

I think its the pro guard i added the my app but im not sure.

Here is my pro gurad settings:

proguard-project.txt:

```
# To enable ProGuard in your project, edit project.properties
# to define the proguard.config property as described in that file.
#
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in ${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the ProGuard
# include property in project.properties.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}


-dontwarn com.google.**
-dontwarn org.apache.**
-dontwarn twitter4j.**
```

project.properties

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
#
# To customize properties used by the Ant build system edit
# "ant.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
# project structure.
#
# To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt

# Project target.
target=android-18



android.library.reference.1=..\\Application\\Libs android\\actionbarsherlock
android.library.reference.2=..\\Application\\Libs android\\facebook-android-sdk-3.5\\facebook
android.library.reference.3=..\\Application\\Libs android\\AmbilWarna
android.library.reference.4=..\\Application\\Libs android\\HoloEverywhere-master\\addons\\preferences
android.library.reference.5=..\\Application\\Libs android\\HoloEverywhere-master\\library
android.library.reference.6=../Application/Libs android/google-play-services_lib
```

Thank for helping!

Comment: What I can see from logcat is: Some error on 22nd line of your xml. So its unable to inflate.

Comment: So why if i install from eclipse its working and from the store it not?

Comment: I think error is coming due to some problem in your xml whenever you define this view org.holoeverywhere.widget.ProgressBar

Comment: How can I say without having a look at xml? Sorry!

Comment: His problem isn't the xml file at all. He've said that this problem only occurs as he download and starts the app via google play. Are you sure that the version you've uploaded to the play store is completly the same version?

Comment: Are you sure the android version on the device downloading the app is the same as the one you used for testing?

Comment: The problem was with the pro guard.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13402408/when-using-proguard-do-you-need-a-separate-config-for-each-referenced-library

Comment: This is the answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13402408/when-using-proguard-do-you-need-a-separate-config-for-each-referenced-library